# How does one send an HTML file through a socket in python?

Tags: python, html, sockets

I'm trying to learn some basic python socket / server programming.  I want to pass my .py file a command line argument, a path to an html file that may or may not exist.  When I connect to the local host through a browser, I want the result to be displayed.  If the file is not found, I want to show an error message. (I've attached my code that does this) I've figured out how to do this by hardcoding the result, but i'm having a hard time figuring the syntax of displaying the resulting html file if it's found.  For reference, here's what the hardcoded part looks like.

```
    c.recv(1000) 
    c.send('HTTP/1.0 200 OK\n')
    c.send('Content-Type: text/html\n')
    c.send('\n') 
    c.send("""
        <html>
        <body>
        <h1>404</h1> FILE NOT FOUND!
        </body>
        </html>
        """) 
    c.close()
```

Comment: Why don't you use python's [`HTTPServer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http.server.HTTPServer)?

Comment: I'm having a hard time figuring out what your question is?

Comment: _want to pass my .py file a command line argument_ If your script executes from the command line, where does the web browser come in?